# Set Basis Problem Variant reference for NP-Completeness?

Tags: np-complete

**Given:** Collection $C$ of Subsets of a finite set $S$, positive integer $K <=|C|$

**Problem Statement:** Is there a collection $B$ of subsets of $S$ with $|B| = K$ such that for each subset $c$ in $C$, there is a sub-collection in $B$ whose union is $c$ ?

This Set Basis Problem is NP-Complete.

If we enforce an additional constraint that $B$ is a subset of $C$, is the problem still NP Complete?

My assumption is yes, but I could not find any reference to this problem. Can anyone please point out to one?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267699

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in fact solvable in polynomial time.

Let 
$$C_0=\Bigl\{c\in C:c\supsetneq\bigcup_{\substack{c'\in C\\c'\subsetneq c}}c'\Bigr\}.$$

On the one hand, if $B\subseteq C$ has the property in the question, then $C_0\subseteq B$: since $c\in C_0$ cannot be written as the union of its proper subsets from $C$, a fortiori it cannot be written as a union of its proper subsets in $B$, hence the only possibility is $c\in B$.

On the other hand, $B=C_0$ *does* have the required property. We prove by induction on $|c|$ that any $c\in C$ is a union of a subcollection of $C_0$: if $c\in C_0$, this holds trivially; otherwise $c$ is the union of its proper subsets in $C$, which in turn can be written as unions of subcollections of $C_0$ by the induction hypothesis.

Thus, the problem is equivalent to $|C_0|\le K$, which can be checked in polynomial time.

Comment: Much thanks. I didn't get an answer here, thus the re-post at mathoverflow. I suppose deleting that should be ok?

Comment: You should wait at least several days before reposting a question. And whatever you do, *always* provide links in both directions between the posts.